# How should I combine docker containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, continuous-integration, rabbitmq, dockerhub

I have a web app that I'm building composed of 3 different parts

1. Node.js API
2. Front end web client, consumes API
3. Node.js service for data processing

I need the 2 node.js services to communicate so I am using rabbitMQ. I want everything to be dockerized because it makes on-boarding and deployment easy. However, I am not sure how to structure the files?

All 3 items should be in **separate github repos** so you can develop them individually, and for organization in general. One giant repo would be a nightmare.

But then how do I combine them at runtime? Should they each be in their own container? How do I pull them together?

Should they all be in one giant folder?

- App

  - node1

    - dockerfile
  - node2

    - dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should they each be in their own container?

Yes, you declare them in a [`docker-compose.yml` similar to this one](https://github.com/CanopyCloud/microservice-nodejs/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), except I would recommend using the [**version 2** of that `docker-compose.yml` format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2) (that supposes Compose 1.6.0+ and a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0+).

That allows for named volumes and [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

As the OP adds in the comments:

> The part I was missing was to upload my separate repos to dockerhub

If each repo represents a docker image, said image, once built, must indeed be uploaded to the docker hub.

Comment: This seems to imply that you have one folder containing all your code, one repo. But how would it work if you had 2 microservices in separate github repos?

Comment: @DylanHarness Having 2 separates repos has no relation with containers: as long as your docker build environment sees those two repos, it can use their content to build any image it needs.

Comment: right right. What does it mean to "see" a repo? What is a "build environment" ? Do I write a docckerfile that git pulls my repos?

Comment: @DylanHarness a "build environment" is the docker *context*: what [**`docker build`** (doc)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) is able to access, ie all the file in the same folder of below where the `docker build` command is run.

Comment: @DylanHarness "Do I write a Dockerfile that git pulls my repos?". No a Dockerfile is the recipe of the environment (docker image) you want to build, in order for a container to represent at runtime (`docker run`) said execution environment. Typically, a Dockerfile is part of your repos, living near your sources, as you can see in [CanopyCloud/microservice-nodejs](https://github.com/CanopyCloud/microservice-nodejs)

Comment: I think it's unclear because this example uses 3 services. 2 images from dockerhub (rabbitmq & mongo) and one local service, the node server. I'm not sure what to do if I have 2 custom node services, should I move them into one giant folder? See edited question for example

Comment: @DylanHarness What you are illustrating in the question is the specification of your environment, not the actual services will will run later in different containers. You could have 3 Dockerfiles in one folder, you could built 3 images and run 3 containers, each representing their own services.

Comment: @DylanHarness Again, the number of repos has nothing to do with the number of services running in containers later.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. The part I was missing was to upload my separate repos to dockerhub

Comment: @DylanHarness Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.